# Insert Copied Cells and Shift Cells down

Tags: excel, vba

Super new to VB macros. I have a title row with formatting that needs to be inserted periodically through my data. So basically I need to insert a static row of cells that is always at the top of my data, periodically throughout the below data.

How can I insert a static copied row of cells into any given row, and then shift the existing rows down?

Here is my attempt:

```
*Sub InsertTitles()
'
' InsertTitles Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+V
'
    ActiveCell.Range("A1:J1").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
End Sub*
```

Answer (score 0):

replace your code with this.

```
   Dim r As Range, n As Integer
   n = ActiveCell.Row
   Set r = Range("A" & n & ":J" & n)
   r.Insert shift:=xlDown
   r.Offset(-1, 0).Value = Range("A1: J1").Value
```